# Avoid Int to double typecast rounding?

Tags: c++, casting

I am converting an `int` to a `double` by dividing the integers by powers of 10. For integers with 7 or greater digits, it appears that rounding is performed when I cast an `int` into a `double`. Why is this happening and how can I avoid this rounding?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double add_decimals(int x, int decimal_places)
{
    double ret = 1.0 * x;
    cout << "x= " << x << endl;
    cout << "ret before changes= " << ret << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < decimal_places; ++i)
    {
        ret /= 10;
    }
    return ret;
}

int main() 
{
    double d = add_decimals(1234566, 2);
    cout << "d= " << d << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any; you're just not observing the values correctly.

Quick fix:

```
std::cout << "d= " << std::fixed << d << endl;
```

You'll need `#include <iomanip>` to use [`std::fixed`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed).